# M is a metric space, then M is open

Tags: general-topology

If M is a metric space, how to prove that M is open by itself. Let x in M , and there exists an open ball centered at x lies in M. How to reason this statement?

Comment: What's the definition of the open ball with centre $x$ and radius $r$?

Answer (score 1):

There can be no elements of a ball about $x$ that are not in $M$. That is, it is necessarily the case that for any radius $r > 0$,

$$B_r(x) = \{ y \in M \ | \ d(x,y) < r \} \ \subset \ M$$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a ball is $B(x,r) = \{y \in M: d(x,y) < r \}$. Take any $r$, say $r=1$. Is this a subset of $M$?